# Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am posting data using `ajax` call to my `.net MVC` controller when my data is small like `base64string` is `100 kb` then all works fine but when I have `base64string` `2mb or 3mb` then ajax directly goes in error. everything is correct but giving error

[image: Error details image]

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/PDF/GeneratePdfWithExhibits',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    base64Data: base64string,
    dataArray: newArray
  }),
  success: function(response) {
    // Retrieve the file URL from the response
    const fileUrl = response.fileUrl;

    // Use the file URL as needed (e.g., open it in a new tab)
    window.open(fileUrl, '_blank');
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.error('XHR:', xhr);
    console.error('Status:', status);
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
});
```

```js
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using iTextSharp.text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

namespace EvidenceReferenceWeb.Controllers {

  public class PDFController: Controller

  {

    public class ObjectClass {
      public string Exhibitid {get;set;}
      public string Affiant {get;set;}
      public string Commissioner {get;set;}
      public string Date {get;set;}
      public string base64 {get;set;}
    }
    public class PdfConversionData {
      public string base64Data {get;set;}
      public List < ObjectClass > ObjectsArray {get;set;}
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GeneratePdfWithExhibits([System.Web.Http.FromBody] PdfConversionData pdfData) {
     
      // Get the URL for the uploaded file
      string fileUrl = Url.Content("~/Uploads/" + fileName);

      // Return the URL as JSON
      return Json(new {
        fileUrl = fileUrl
      });
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried lot of things like ` <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>` in my Web.config file